# PhoneGap: Install and use plugin

Tags: typescript, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

Here is the command I used to install fileOpener2:

```
phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-file-opener2
```

After executing command, it says it adds it, and it shows up in my config.xml file.  And is added to the plugins directory.  However it never works.

Here is below ts that i've tried.  All 3 fail to work:

```
try{
    (<any> window).plugins.fileOpener.open(myFileUrl);                        
} catch(e) {
    alert(e);
}
try{
    (<any> cordova).plugins.fileOpener2.open(myFileUrl, 'application/pdf');
} catch(e) {
    alert(e);
}
try{
    (<any> window).plugins.fileOpener2.open(myFileUrl, 'application/pdf');
} catch(e) {
    alert(e);
}
```

Error of all 3:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

Couple of extra details.  This is in an angular app.  And this isn't called immediately.

Comment: Are you using the phonegap developer app to test?

Comment: @jcesarmobile yea, I'm using the phonegap app to test.  Will it only work with a full build?

Comment: yes, the phonegap app has all the core plugins installed and some of the 3rd party ones, but probably not the file opener plugin, so it won't work there.